# Using dplyr to calculate values by conditional but end up with a dataframe with one row

Tags: r, dplyr

```
shop <- c("AB2", "AB2", "GH7", "GH7", "PO1")
sales <- c(12, 43, 76, 54, NA)
county <- c("Orange", "Orange", "Sperling", "Sperling", "Wood")
df <- data.frame(shop, county, sales)
```

I am trying to calculate the minimum and maximum sales by store. I've tried two solutions so far.
First:

```
new_df <- df %>%
  group_by(county, shop) %>%
  summarise(
    max_time = max(sales, na.rm=TRUE),
    min_time = min(sales, na.rm=TRUE))

new_df <- df %>%
  group_by(county, shop) %>%
  filter(minimum == min(sales, na.rm=TRUE),
         maximum == max(sales, na.rm=TRUE))
```

When I try this, I get the following outcome:

```
max_time  min_time
76        12
```

Clearly, R is reading it as the maximum and minimum time within the dataframe. I figured the group_by function would have done the trick but clearly it didn't work. How do I get it to calculate and return a dataset for all county, shop combinations?

Comment: The 1st solution with `summarise` produces 3 row dataframe for me. Do you have `plyr` loaded which is masking the summarise function. Try using `dplyr::summarise` instead.

Comment: Optional: `new_df <- data.table::setDT(df)[!is.na(sales), .(max_time = max(sales), min_time = min(sales)), by = .(county,shop)]`

Answer (score 1):

In this instance, `summarise` is coming from the `plyr` package rather than `dplyr`. You just need to be explicit with the package.

```
library(dplyr)

new_df <- df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(county, shop) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(
    max_time = max(sales, na.rm=TRUE),
    min_time = min(sales, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   county [3]
  county   shop  max_time min_time
  <chr>    <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 Orange   AB2         43       12
2 Sperling GH7         76       54
3 Wood     PO1       -Inf      Inf
```